# How to get the warning message as a string when validating XML with schemaValidate() in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, xsd

I have this code to validate an XML file against an XSD file:

```
$file = 'test.xml';
$schema = 'test.xsd';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load($file);


if ($dom->schemaValidate($schema)) {
    print "$file is valid.\n";
} else {
    print "$file is invalid.\n";
}
```

If the xml file is invalid, then it says that it is invalid.
The reason it is invalid (e.g. price is not an integer), however, is only given in a PHP warning, which I have to suppress so that user doesn't see it (with error_reporting(0)).

How can I get the text of that message and pass it on to the user, as I would do in C# with a try/catch?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you can use [`libxml`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.libxml.php)'s error handling functions for this one:

- [`libxml_use_internal_errors()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php) to switch to user error handling
- [`libxml_get_errors()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-errors.php) to retrieve the errors from the `libxml` error buffer; this will return an array of [`libXMLError`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.libxmlerror.php) objects
- [`libxml_clear_errors()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-clear-errors.php) to clear the `libxml` error buffer

Simple example:

```
$file = 'test.xml';
$schema = 'test.xsd';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load($file);

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);     
if ($dom->schemaValidate($schema)) {
    print "$file is valid.\n";
} else {
    print "$file is invalid.\n";
    $errors = libxml_get_errors();
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        printf('XML error "%s" [%d] (Code %d) in %s on line %d column %d' . "\n",
            $error->message, $error->level, $error->code, $error->file,
            $error->line, $error->column);
    }
    libxml_clear_errors();
}
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to print, you can define your custom [error handler](http://hu2.php.net/set_error_handler) to print the error.

Answer (score 0):

here is how i did it:

```
$errs = [ ];
set_error_handler ( function ($severity, $message, $file, $line) use (&$errs) {
    $errs [] = $message;
} );
$validated = $domd->schemaValidate ( 'factinv-3-0.xsd' );
restore_error_handler ();
```

error descriptions are now in $errs, if any.